# ”Ambiguous user-defined-conversion“ error in cmake(vs2019) but no error in normal vs2019

Tags: c++

I have a header file that is fine in a normal vs project, but in a cmake-generated project it has a compilation error.
Here is the code:

```cpp
struct B  {
    operator /*const*/ int *() const { return p; } 
    int *p;
};

struct  A : public B {
    operator int * &&() && {
        auto r = p;
        p = nullptr;
        return std::move(p);
    }
};

void fun() {
    A a;
    int *f = a;
    int *b = std::move(a);
}
```

there are error info in cmake-generated project:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'A' to 'int *'
message : Ambiguous user-defined-conversion
```

**project config:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz1OE.png)

Comment: Note that msvc rejects the program but gcc and clang accept it. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c4Tn1nPf7)

Comment: Also note that the pointer data member `p` is uninitialized, so returning it like `return p;` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Seems like a msvc bug. MSVC rejects it with c++17 but starts accepting with C++20. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/on6EnvGo5)

Comment: @user12002570 umm Ackchyually. Returning it is not a UB. Dereferencing it is.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat You're wrong because returning it is also UB as it is uninitialized. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/szEno56dx). This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @user12002570 No it is not in itself undefined behavior. It may lead to one that why the warnings. Turn on `-fsanatize=undefined` for a quick demo. But the standard does not mention it. It only talks about accessing `uninitialized` objects and pointers. https://godbolt.org/z/K4fvaMM7x

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat No, there is a conceptual copy(before c++17) when returning by value. And hence this cannot be relied upon as it has UB as per the standard. Whether or not compilers have implemented this correctly is another matter. I explained the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76324719/12002570).

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat [Prior to C++17 there is a conceptual copy here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76324719/12002570) and since `ptr` is uninitialized it is UB.

Comment: @user12002570 This tells me that this behavior is completely well-defined even before `C++17`. `T*` is not a class type. So, the last effect applies which is copy initialization with potential implict-conversion. `T*` -> `T*` does not need conversion so it is going to initialize with whichever value the uninitialized pointer has. Copy initialization of pointers is well defined.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat Are you implying that `void func(int*){} int main(){int *i; func(i);}` is also well-defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256360/discussion-between-ajinkya-kamat-and-user12002570).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparison, I found the reason.

in vs set "c/c++/Language/Conformance mode" to "Yes(/permissiv-)"

in cmake add add_compile_options("/permissive-")

or change code, I think it's the perfect solution.

```cpp
struct B  {
    operator const int *() const { return p; } //add const
    int *p;
};

struct  A : public B {
    operator int * &&() && {
        auto r = p;
        p = nullptr;
        return std::move(p);
    }
};

void fun() {
    A a;
    const int *f = a;  //add const
    int *b = std::move(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a msvc bug. MSVC rejects it with C++17 but starts accepting it with C++20. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/89s1K89a3).

##### Note

Note that data member `p` of primitive type remains uninitialized with default initialization in your program unless you explicitly provide a default ctor that initializes it or use in-class initializer. So using(other than assignment to it) that uninitialized member can lead to undefined behavior.

Clang gives a warning with `-Wall`:

```
 warning: 'a' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   18 |     int *f = a;
```

Comment: thinks,the code isn't real, it's used to describe the problem, so it's not rigorous.  Maybe it is a vs bug